# Phonegap sound not playing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I can't get Phonegap to play custom sound. Below is my code, i got it from examples that people said it works. But it isnt working on mine.

```
var file = 'sound.mp3';
    if ( (typeof device != 'undefined') && (device.platform == 'Android') ) {
      var  file2 = '/android_asset/www/media' + file ;
               new Media( file2 ).play();

    } 
    if (typeof Media != 'undefined') {
       new Media( file2 ).play();
    }
    else {
               new Media( file ).play();

    }
```

I also tried simply this

```
 var my_media = new Media('/android_asset/www/media/sound.mp3');
                my_media.play();
```

Nothing works.

I have the below set in config.xml

```
   <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Combined the 2 options

```
var file = 'sound.mp3';
    if ( (typeof device != 'undefined') && (device.platform == 'Android') ) {
   var my_media = new Media('/android_asset/www/media/sound.mp3');
                my_media.play();

    } 
    if (typeof Media != 'undefined') {
     var my_media = new Media('/android_asset/www/media/sound.mp3');
                my_media.play();
    }
    else {
               var my_media = new Media('/media/sound.mp3');
                my_media.play();

    }
```